# How to make a custom Checkbox like Motorola's TaskManager?

Tags: android, checkbox, taskmanager

I'm currently developing an app for the android platform. I have a DROID 3 which comes with Motorola's Task Manager (v10.0). I'm looking to emulate the style of the checkbox as seen here:
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-TQ42DlBJYk8/Th8dYkESrMI/AAAAAAAAPuM/n1FnPXoCRMY/droid3-13.jpg

I Tried to embed a ImageView and TextView inside a CheckBox, but it gives a ClassCastException, so that idea's out:
android.widget.CheckBox cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I'll keep looking for a solution and post if I find one.

Comment: The check box you shown in image is default text box of android in SDK 4.0

Answer (score 0):

One possibility could be to create your own images. Throw away the CheckBox, then set an OnClickListener on an ImageView, and when you click you change the source of the ImageView, and change some global boolean value to note whether it is checked or not.

That is one method.

Or according to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html, the `View` xml attributes work, therefore you could call `checkBox.setBackgroundResource(resid)` to change the appearance. That may not change the CheckBox itself, though. I'm guessing it doesn't.

I'm thinking the best solution is an `ImageView` and a separate TextView, though. Tedious, but should work, I think.